# bash run php with multiple parameters

Tags: php, bash

```
/usr/local/bin/php54-cli -d memory_limit=-1 && disable_functions=""  composer.phar create-project kunstmaan/bundles-standard-edition admin
```

I'm trying to run composer with multiple parameters:

```
-d memory_limit=-1 && disable_functions=
```

This is not correct way because I get running script in background

Comment: Not a really challenging question, but why downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use define multiple times:

```
-bash-4.1$ /usr/local/bin/php54-cli -d memory_limit=-1 -d disable_functions=""  composer.phar create-project kunstmaan/bundles-standard-edition admin
```